# Fast file content generating via bash

Tags: bash, unix

The task is to write script in bash that will be generating numbers from 1 to some number while the size of file is less than 5 Mb. I've written the script but it is too slow. How can I improve it's speed to 2 seconds?

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! [ -f task3.txt ]
then
        touch task3.txt
fi
limit=5242880
size=`wc -c < task3.txt`
i=1
while [ $size -le $limit ]
do
        echo "$i " >> task3.txt
        i=$((i+1))
        size=`wc -c < task3.txt`
done
```

Comment: Figure out how many numbers you need first.

Comment: Make a small RAMdisk for the output file at step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running to the file system and counting every byte again every time to figure out how much you've written, keep the count yourself. As it is currently written, you could use

```
size=$((size + ${#i} + 2))
```

inside the loop. Here `${#i}` is the length of `$i`, and it's two more per loop because you echo a space and a newline in addition to it. If the space is a typo, as I suspect, then your loop could be

```
while [ $size -le $limit ]
do
    echo "$i" >> task3.txt     # cut space
    i=$((i+1))
    size=$((size + ${#i} + 1)) # only +1 here.
done
```

Furthermore, to avoid opening and closing the pipe all the time, you could write

```
while [ $size -le $limit ]
do
    echo "$i"                  # cut space
    i=$((i+1))
    size=$((size + ${#i} + 1)) # only +1 here.
done >> task3.txt
```

this doesn't cut the running time down quite as much as removing the `wc -c`, but it was still ~50% (so worth it).

**Addendum for great speed:**

Another way to do this that is much, much faster than the manual loop is to abuse `seq` as follows:

```
left=$((limit - size))      # bytes left to write

seq 1 $left | head -c $left >> task3.txt
```

This abuses the fact that `head -c $left` stops reading after `$left` bytes, at which point `seq`'s stdout closes and `seq` also stops writing, and that `seq 1 $left` will print more than `$left` bytes of output. The caveat is that it writes not n numbers but n bytes, so the last number in the output may be truncated. It is not in this particular case when starting from an empty file, but that is by chance.

Thanks to @gniourf_gniourf for coming up with most of this one.

Comment: Put the redirection after the `done` keyword too! this should improve its speed a lot!

Comment: Believe it or not, I was just writing that up (great minds think alike, hrhr). brings it down from 20 to 10 seconds -- not as big a chunk as the (probably) several hours from the other bit, but still good. I'll now meditate whether there's an easy formula to calculate the needed numbers in advance because `seq 1 764855 > task3.txt` executes in (much) less than a second.

Comment: Also, maybe `done >> task3.txt` is better since OP doesn't start with an empty file.

Comment: How about: (1) determine the initial size of file. (2) compute how many bytes left are needed to go to 5MB (`$bytesleft`). (3) use this wonderful pipeline: `yes '' | nl -b a -n ln`. (4) pipe this through `head -c "$bytesleft" >> task3.txt`. `:)`

Comment: With this I got it in `real 0m0.197s`. Can you beat that? `:)`

Comment: As a matter of fact, yes, by a factor of 8, using `seq 1 $bytesleft` instead of `yes '' | nl -b -a -n ln`. But that is a very nifty trick, and I don't think I'd have come up with it myself. Do you want to make it an answer or shall I put it in? Oh, and I fixed the `>` vs. `>>` bit from before, although I'd be surprised if OP really intended to start from a non-empty file.

Comment: Add it in your answer `;)`

Comment: Oh, hold on -- that'll cut the last number off in the middle, won't it? It's just lucky that it fits precisely with 5242880.

Comment: Yes it might cut the last number (and even have an incomplete line)... but you'll get exactly 5000000 bytes!

Comment: And what does the key "-c" mean when using with command "head"?

Comment: To take the first n bytes instead of lines. You can read more about it with `man head`.